# Minimal polynomials over ${\mathbb Q}$ for roots of a polynomial with algebraic coefficients

Tags: galois-theory

Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ with algebraic coefficients; then all roots $\{\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n\}$ of $P(x)$ are also algebraic.
Now suppose, in addition, that all coefficients of $P(x)$ have minimal polynomials of degree $\le D$ over ${\mathbb Q}$.

Given $n$ and $D$, what's a good upper bound on the degree of minimal polynomials over ${\mathbb Q}$ for the roots $\{\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n\}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best can do with the information we have is the following:

The constant coefficient of $P$ is contained in an extension $K_1/\Bbb Q$ of degree at most $D$. The first degree coefficient of $P$ is contained in an extension $K'_2/\Bbb Q$ of degree at most $D$, which means that it's contained in an extension $K_2/K_1$ of degree at most $D$. Therefore, the linear and constant coefficients are contained together in an extension $K_2/\Bbb Q$ of degree at most $D^2$.

Continuing this way, we see that $P$ is a polynomial where all the coefficients lie in an extension $K_{n+1}/\Bbb Q$ of degree at most $D^{n+1}$. Finally, the roots of $P$ lie in an extension $K/K_{n+1}$ of degree at most $n!$, so we conclude that $K/\Bbb Q$ has degree at most $n!D^{n+1}$.
At the same time,  the minimal polynomial of each individual $\alpha_k$ has degree bounded by $nD^{n+1}$.

Comment: And presumably, this is generically the right answer, for example if the coefficients of $P$ are $D$th roots of distinct prime numbers.

Comment: @GregMartin Yes, I should've mentioned that the bound can be attained quite easily, so with only $n$ and $D$ to work with, this is the sharpest bound you can get. If we ever got more specific information about the coefficients, then this changes drastically. For instance, if coefficient $a_m$ has degree $D_m$, then my proof is easily adapted to obtain the bound $nD_0D_1\cdots D_{n}$.

Comment: @GregMartin Small brain fart: a polynomial of degree $n$ has all its roots contained in an extension of degree at most $n!$, not at most $n$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Somehow I suspected that the upper bound might also depend on whether the coefficients of $P(x)$ are/are not expressible as radicals, but that seems to be a red herring.

Comment: I think the question could be stated slightly more clearly, but the minimal polynomial of each individual $\alpha_k$ does have degree bounded by $nD^{n+1}$. The bound of $n!D^{n+1}$ is for (I think) a related but different question.

Comment: @GregMartin You're right. The question asks about the degree of the minimal polynomials, not the splitting field.

Answer (score 1):

Take the number field generated by all the alphas.  Find its degree (not an easy computational problem!). Call it $m$. Then the upper bound is the  product of degree of $P(x)$ and $m$.

Example: if $P(X)= X^2 + \sqrt2 X + (\sqrt2+3)$ then 4 is a bound.

If $P(X) = X^2 +\sqrt2 X +\sqrt3$ then the  upper bound is 8.